# Django models and orm and foreign key problems

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

i want got all of related model's data, but i got only some of related data. to avoid N+1 problem, i used select_related() and prefetch_related() methods.

At first, i have these models:

```
class OrderList(models.Model):
    order_id=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order_status=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProductInOrder(models.Model):
    order_key=models.ForeignKey(OrderList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="order_key")
    
    product_id=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_price=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class MemosInProduct(models.Model):
    product_key=models.ForeignKey(ProductInOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_key")

    memo=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    blahblah some codes...
```

a short explan of this models, one OrderList has got many of ProductInOrder ( one to many )
and one ProductInOrder has got many of MemosInProduct( one to many )

then, i run this codes in django shell:

```
order_list=OrderList.object.select_related("order_key", "product_key").all()
```

i excepted all of OrderList datas with related all of datas combine with it(product, memos):
**EXCEPTED**

> order_list[0].order_key[0].product_key[0].memo
> order_list[0].order_key[0].product_key[1].memo
> order_list[0].order_key[1].product_key[0].memo
> ...

but i got:
**OUTPUT**

> Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'order_key', 'product_key'. Choices are: (none)

i also tried this:

```
order_list=MemosInProduct.object.select_related("order_key", "product_key").all()
```

but outputs are not matched i except.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/) `select_related` fetch the related object(foreign key relationship) if the foreign key is present in the model. That means it fetches the forward-related objects.

For example:

```
def OrderList(models.Model):
    order_id=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order_status=models.CharField(max_length=100))
```

You can't use `select_related` as there are no forward relations in this model. So, Django raises errors.

> Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'order_key', 'product_key'. Choices are: (none)

But, you can use `select_related` for `ProductInOrder` and `MemosInProduct` as there are forward relationships which are `order_key` and `product_key` respectively for `ProductInOrder` and `MemosInProduct`.

For backward relationships (the foreign key is not present in the query model) you should use `prefetch_related`.

So, In your case, the query should be

```
OrderList.objects.prefetch_related("order_key", "order_key__product_key").all()
```

Here, you can see I also changed the `product_key` to `order_key__product_key` because the `product_key` is not the related object of the `OrderList` it is a related object of `ProductInOrder`

This is the theory though. Maybe you need to use `Prefetch` in your query. An example

```
OrderList.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('order_key', queryset=ProductInOrder.objects.all(), to_attr='order_keys')).all()
```

However, read the Django docs for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tackle this by working in the opposite direction, and retrieve `MemosInProduct` objects each with their related objects. For example, to get everything related to OrderList objects with `order_status = 'overdue'` (I'm guessing):

```
queryset = MemosInProduct.objects.order_by(
               'product_key__order__key__order_id',
               'product_key__product_id'
            ).select_related(
               'product_key', 'product_key__order_key'
            ).filter(
               product_key__order__key__order_status='overdue'
            )
```

In the loop over the retrieved objects you can tell when you have progressed to a different ProductInOrder or OrderList if you keep track of the previous item within the loop

```
last_object = None
for memo in queryset:
    product = memo.product_key
    order = product.order_key
    if ( last_object is None or 
         last_object.product_key.order_id != order.id ):
       # do stuff for a changed order compared to last (or the first loop)
    if ( last_object is None or 
         last_object.product_key_id != product.pk) :
       # do stuff for a changed product compared to last

    # do stuff for every memo
    last_object = memo
```

Alternatively you can construct a list of lists of lists, which is an easy thing to walk through in the template language  when passed in the  context to be rendered.

Remember that Python assignment is name-binding, not object-copying, so this sort of thing is efficient. In the loop, product and order were prefetched by the `select_related`.

Comment: thanks man, what a great answer. but Almabud's answer is more fit my situation. but really thank you.